# Drawing a FacetGrid of QQ-plots with seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, statistics, seaborn

I am unable to draw a [FacetGrid](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) of [QQ-plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) with [seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html).

I have a matrix of m rows (observations) and n columns (features), and I want to draw a QQ-plot for each feature (column) to compare it with the normal distribution.

So far, my code is like this:

```
import scipy.stats as ss

def qqplots(fpath, expr, title):

    def quantile_plot(x, **kwargs):
        x = ss.zscore(x)
        qntls, xr = ss.probplot(x, dist="norm")
        plt.scatter(xr, qntls, **kwargs)

    expr_m = pd.melt(expr)
    expr_m.columns = ["Feature", "Value"]
    n_feat = len(expr_m["Feature"].value_counts().index)

    n_cols = int(np.sqrt(n_feat)) + 1

    g = sns.FacetGrid(expr_m, col="Feature", col_wrap=n_cols)
    g.map(quantile_plot, "Value");
    plt.savefig(fpath + ".pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.savefig(fpath + ".png", bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.close()

qqplots("lognorm_qqplot", np.log2(expr), "Log-normal qqplot")
```

The `expr` variable is a pandas DataFrame with m rows (observations) and n columns (features).

The Exception I get is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-f9333a55702e> in <module>()
     39     plt.close()
     40 
---> 41 qqplots("lognorm_qqplot", np.log2(expr), "Log-normal qqplot")

<ipython-input-52-f9333a55702e> in qqplots(fpath, expr, title)
     34 
     35     g = sns.FacetGrid(expr_m, col="Feature", col_wrap=n_cols)
---> 36     g.map(quantile_plot, "Value");
     37     plt.savefig(fpath + ".pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
     38     plt.savefig(fpath + ".png", bbox_inches="tight")

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in map(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    726 
    727             # Draw the plot
--> 728             self._facet_plot(func, ax, plot_args, kwargs)
    729 
    730         # Finalize the annotations and layout

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in _facet_plot(self, func, ax, plot_args, plot_kwargs)
    810 
    811         # Draw the plot
--> 812         func(*plot_args, **plot_kwargs)
    813 
    814         # Sort out the supporting information

<ipython-input-52-f9333a55702e> in quantile_plot(y, **kwargs)
     25         y = ss.zscore(y)
     26         qntls, xr = ss.probplot(y, dist="norm")
---> 27         plt.scatter(xr, qntls, **kwargs)
     28 
     29     expr_m = pd.melt(expr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3249                          vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha,
   3250                          linewidths=linewidths, verts=verts,
-> 3251                          edgecolors=edgecolors, data=data, **kwargs)
   3252     finally:
   3253         ax.hold(washold)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1810                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1811                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1812             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1813         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1814         if pre_doc is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   3838         y = np.ma.ravel(y)
   3839         if x.size != y.size:
-> 3840             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
   3841 
   3842         s = np.ma.ravel(s)  # This doesn't have to match x, y in size.

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Comment: is 'ss' a global variable or a module?!

Comment: Oops, forgot to add. It is `scipy.stats`. Editing thanks

Comment: @fbrundu not an answer, but you might want to look at how I implemented this here: http://phobson.github.io/mpl-probscale/tutorial/closer_look_at_viz.html#mapping-probability-plots-to-seaborn-facetgrids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved this, and also changed the color to use the Seaborn color palette, with the following code:

```
def qqplots(fpath, expr, title):

    def quantile_plot(x, **kwargs):
        x = ss.zscore(x)
        ss.probplot(x, plot=plt)

    expr_m = pd.melt(expr)
    expr_m.columns = ["Feature", "Value"]
    n_feat = len(expr_m["Feature"].value_counts().index)

    n_cols = int(np.sqrt(n_feat)) + 1

    g = sns.FacetGrid(expr_m, col="Feature", col_wrap=n_cols)
    g.map(quantile_plot, "Value");
    for ax in g.axes:
        ax.get_lines()[0].set_markerfacecolor(sns.color_palette()[0])
        ax.get_lines()[1].set_color(sns.color_palette()[3])
    plt.savefig(fpath + ".pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.savefig(fpath + ".png", bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.close()

qqplots("lognorm_qqplot", np.log2(expr), "Log-normal qqplot")
```

Comment: This answer seems to break when applying `qqplot` from `statsmodels.api`. I get an empty grid of plot followed by each individual `qqplot`.

Comment: I am unable to test it now. If the code is not working anymore please post another answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question: "I am unable to draw a FacetGrid of QQ-plots with seaborn.", I give you here an example with dataset `tips` from `seaborn`.

To draw qqplots, one of the best approaches is to use the `statsmodels` library which has the [qqplot](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html) function built into it. This function generates a new figure if the given `ax` is not passed as an argument. Therefore, using `FacetGrid.map()` with this function generates individual figures instead of plotting everything on the grid.
To deal with this, you can use a user-defined function in which `sm.qqplots` retrieves the current `ax` thanks to `plt.gca()`. Here I created a new function called `qqplot_new`. Here the qqplots are like test for normality of data.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

def qqplot_new(x, ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    sm.qqplot(x, ax=ax, **kwargs)
    
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  row="sex")
g.map(qqplot_new, "total_bill", line='s')
```

[Output : Figure obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIFcs.png)